Issues with Bootstrap rendering in DomPDF
I am facing issues with the Bootstrap. I have read a few posts that it works well with bootstrap 3.3.7, so I have used it. But to my surprise, it is not working. I don't know what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the code I have used:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <style>
            <?php echo file_get_contents(BASEURL . 'public/assests/css/bootstrap_3_3_7.min.css'); ?>
            .p-3 {
                padding: 0.7rem !important;
            }
            .mb-4 {
                margin-bottom: 1.5rem !important;
            }
            .border {
                border: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body style="font-size: 18px !important;">
        <div class="container mt-2">
            <div class="row border p-3 mb-4">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <label for="" class="form-label">Code</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="11">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <label for="" class="form-label">Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="22">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <label for="" class="form-label">Email</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="33">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <label for="" class="form-label">Contact Number</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="44">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>

This is the pdf I am getting:

I have got 2 issues here:

Why the last text box is out of the 'border' property box?
Why is there a lots of space on both sides?

Thanks in advance.
